# Sending changes from Planner Calendar's Tasks to User's Outlook Calendar

Tags: power-automate, office365-apps, outlook-calendar, microsoft-planner

I am in the process of creating a Flow that can add/delete/update events in a user's Outlook calendar when the respective task in Planner is added/deleted/updated. I have been able to successfully get adding and deleting events in Planner's tasks to reflect their respective event changes in the user's Outlook calendar. The problem I'm running into is with updating events. It seems like the Flow I've created isn't able to adjust an existing event's dates in the user's Outlook calendar when the respective Planner task's dates are changed. I'm wondering if there might be something I'm missing here?

Thanks for taking the time to help!

Here is the Flow I've created so far:
[image]